# Why is changing the type of column causing extensive autovacuum?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, vacuum

I changed the type of a column from `varchar` to `uuid` in a table with a couple of million rows. This caused quite an extensive autovacuum.

Can somebody explain why this is required and should I have done a `vacuum full`?

I am working with Postges 13.8.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the type with

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col TYPE uuid USING col::uuid;
```

that will *not* trigger an autovacuum run. I guess that it was a coincidence that autovacuum launched a worker on the table.

Don't run `VACUUM (FULL)`.